# ret, frame = video_capture.read() ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, face-recognition

I want to use IP cam instead of webcam on my project which is based on tiny face detection.

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
video_capture=VideoStream("rtsp://admin:bilge06@10.374.140.132:554").start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python

```
capture= cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:bilge06@10.374.140.132:554")

if not capture:
    print("Failed")
else:
   ret, frame= capture.read()
```

It is in C++
You need change the code as

```
VideoCapture capture;
Mat ImageMat;
bool op = capture.open("rtsp://admin:bilge06@10.374.140.132:554");
if(op)
{
    capture >> ImageMat;
}
```

It will read from the stream. To check whether stream is working or not you can use VLC player and set the IP in network stream and it will verify it